# How to clear the file after uploading?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, file-upload

I am using visual developer 2012 and have a simple form to upload the file to the server and then enter the name of the file into another table. For whatever reason it runs twice and enter the values twice in the second table:

```
Protected Sub BtnUploadImg_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles BtnUploadImg.Click
    If IsPostBack Then
        ' Dim CurrentPath As String = Server.MapPath("C:\DSimages\")
        If FileUpLoad1.HasFile = True Then
            Try
                FileUpLoad1.SaveAs("C:\DSimages\" & _
                   FileUpLoad1.FileName)
                Label1.Text = "File name: " & _
                   FileUpLoad1.PostedFile.FileName & "<br>" & _
                   "File Size: " & _
                   FileUpLoad1.PostedFile.ContentLength & " kb<br>" & _
                   "Content type: " & _
                   FileUpLoad1.PostedFile.ContentType
                ImageDataSource.InsertParameters("ImgName").DefaultValue = FileUpLoad1.PostedFile.FileName
            Catch ex As Exception
                Label1.Text = "ERROR: " & ex.Message.ToString()
            End Try
        Else
            Label1.Text = "You have not specified a file."
        End If
    End If

    ImageDataSource.Insert()
    FileUpLoad1.PostedFile.InputStream.Dispose()     

End Sub
```

---

Comment: Did you try debugging to understand *why* it runs twice?

Comment: Is this the only method in your source? It sounds like you are saving the image more than once because of a second call.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have the same code under the page load event? The postback will fire both events, so if you do it will run twice.

Comment: I deleted the file and recreated it and it was fine